# Matching text in cells of one column against cells in columns with a variable number of rows

Tags: excel, vba, match, string-matching

I have an Excel file with two sheets: Master and sheet two.
Master has one column of roughly 50 rows each containing a word.
Sheet two has 23 columns of varying lengths, the largest going up to 95 rows.

My goal is to use column one on Master to search each column on sheet 2 for text matches and then output all the matches below their respective columns on sheet 2.

The issue is after the first column on sheet 2 the matching often misses words.

```vb
Sub CompareFNL()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheets("Master")

Dim rng As Range
Dim Column2 As Integer
Dim RowsMaster As Integer, Rows2 As Integer

RowsMaster = WS.Cells(100, 1).End(xlUp).row
Rows2 = Worksheets(2).Cells(100, 1).End(xlUp).row

Column2 = Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 24).End(xlToRight).Column

' Get the number of used rows for each sheet
With Worksheets(2)
    For c = 1 To Column2
    
        For i = 1 To Rows2
            'Loop through Sheet 2
        
            For j = 1 To RowsMaster
                'Loop through the Master sheet
            
                If .Cells(i, c) = WS.Cells(j, 1) Then
                    'If a match is found:
                    Worksheets(2).Cells(i + 110, c) = WS.Cells(j, 1)
                    'Copy int sheet2 in their respective columns
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Next c

    'Store blank cells inside a variable

    On Error GoTo NoBlanksFound
    Set rng = Range("a110:x250").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Delete blank cells and shift upward
    rng.Rows.delete Shift:=xlShiftUp

'ERROR HANLDER
NoBlanksFound:
    MsgBox "No Blank cells were found"

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Here's a useful VBA resource: a [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to fix your indentation.

Comment: Have you attempted to look at variant arrays?  Looping through variant arrays, particularly with `InStr()` would get *like* matches, and would be fairly quick compared to having Excel go cell to cell, sheet to sheet.

Comment: @Cyril, unfortunately I need exact matches.

Comment: @MattPatt Then you can do `if array_a(i,j) = array_b(r,c) then` for exact matches.  Do you have issues with leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: Overall, have you inspected the actual strings of the lookup and the expected-match values to ensure they are *exactly* the same?

Comment: @Cyril Yes they are exact matches as it works perfectly in column one of sheet 2 but then gets spotty after column one. I'm wondering if its an issue with the code or an issue with the limitations of Excel VBA (asking it to do too much but the code si okay)

Answer (score 0):

can you add .Cells(i,j).Value to see whether it works or not:

```
If .Cells(i, c).Value = WS.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
```